Why is $Δω=R/L$ in quality factors derivation?
I was studying the derivation of quality factor and bandwidth regarding what it is. There it was written
$$Q=\frac{\overset{\tiny \blacktriangle}{\omega}}{\Delta\omega},$$
where $\overset{\tiny \blacktriangle}{\omega}$ is the resonant frequency and $\Delta\omega=R/L$ is the FWHM (the difference between frequencies at which the power is half the maximum power at resonance).
My main question here is: why is this $\Delta \omega =R/L?$ How is this equation derived? I also saw some derivations of lower and upper cut-off, but this was also not mentioned there.
[I am currently in 12th standard, so there could be the possibility I don't know some things. Please tell me about it, even if it is basic or advanced at any level.]
Where I can find answer to this ques or such ques. In which books or wherever.
Please refer to books I can read to go more deep into subject and think about more such questions.

But I think I got the answer it can be done through the differential calculus. I saw similar equation in electromagnetic damping. Like the one I saw in upper and lower cut. So do I have to make an equation which would be of order 2. In form of dq . Then I have to solve. It.

Am I thinking correctly.  Please tell and also. Still please refer to the materials I can read. And possible explanations to it  ... I would love to understand this deeply.

If you think you have answered your own question, please consider writing your answer in the answer box below, in order to help future readers with the same question.

For a series RLC circuit the magnitude of the impedance is given by $Z^2=\left( \omega L -\frac {1}{\omega C}\right)^2+R^2$.
For current resonance this impedance is a minimum with a magnitude $R$ so $\left( \omega L -\frac {1}{\omega C}\right)=0\Rightarrow \omega_0^2 = \frac{1}{LC}$.
By definition the bandwidth is the difference in the two frequencies either side of the resonant frequency when the power dissipated in the circuit is half that at resonance, $I^2R$, which means that the magnitude of the current is $1/\sqrt 2$ of its value at resonance.
Thus the impedance of the circuit has to be of magnitude $\sqrt2 R$.
$(\sqrt 2 R)^2=\left( \omega L -\frac {1}{\omega C}\right)^2+R^2\Rightarrow \left( \omega L -\frac {1}{\omega C}\right)= \pm R$ which gives two quadratic equations which when solved give the upper and lower frequencies when the power is a half of that at resonance.
$\omega_{\rm L}=-\frac{R}{2L}+\sqrt {\left( \left( \frac{R}{2L}\right)^2+ \frac {1}{LC}\right)}$ and $\omega_{\rm H}=\frac{R}{2L}+\sqrt {\left( \left( \frac{R}{2L}\right)^2+ \frac {1}{LC}\right)}$
This gives the bandwidth, $\Delta \omega = \omega _{\rm H} - \omega _{\rm L}= \frac RL$.
